# what is "field_create_field" and "hook_field_info"? is there difference motive

Tags: entities, hooks

I want to create a field, i searched on drupal and find field_create_field can create a field but I also find that hook_field_info is also to create to field.

My question is what is basic difference between both of them?
Are they use for same purpose?

I need the difference and where both are used?

Answer (score 3):

**function field_create_field** is used to create a field. When you debug this function you will get $field array with the id property filled in.

**function hook_field_info** defines Field API field types. For more info refer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54647/where-can-i-find-complete-documentation-of-hook-field-info).

For more clarification you can simply debug both these functions then you will get the all basic differences.

Answer (score 1):

`field_create_field` can create field object with passing the **field definition** as function argument.

`hook_field_info` can only define the **field definition**.

The main reason why we need a separate function to define **field definition** is to get benefit from the **alter** behavior of Drupal (e.g. `hook_field_info_alter`). It is what I guess.

Comment: You're right about the alter functionality, but I think the main point for the OP is that hook_field_info is for declaring **types** of field, and field_create_field is for creating the fields themselves

Comment: @Clive yes. My idea is types does matter because there is alter function. It is the only extra behavior provided by `hook_xxx_info` I can think of, otherwise, a separate function for defining field type is not necessary if we don't need to consider the ease of code management.

Comment: @JimmyKo the both do same work ? Means i can define fields and create them using hook_field_info and supported function like widget and formatter hook?

Comment: @VarunPandey Nope, they are not doing same work. `hook_field_info` return array with field key which contains the properties of field. `hook_create_field` is to read the array for forming the database query to create table and other DB operations.